# Compose UI: How to query the semantic tree at runtime (not in test)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In my app I want to display some sort of tutorial to guide users through the app - something like [this](https://github.com/shripal17/MaterialIntroView-v2). The app already uses tutorials in other parts therefore I want to integrate Compose UI support into the existing tutorial framework.

For this purpose I need to get the position and size of several composables. Therefore I want to set semantic
properties to the views I want to identify like this:

```
Text(text = text, Modifier.semantics {
    set(customPropertyKey, "CustomValue")
})
```

How can I query the semantics tree in order to find out details like position and size about the composable with the value `"CustomValue"`?

This is possible in Junit tests using `composeTestRule.onNode(...)`. However, how can I do that **at runtime** (not in a unit test)?

I know that reading the position and size might work using the `onGloballyPositioned` callbacak but this would lead to much boilerplate code which I try to avoid.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Can you explain what problem you're trying to solve first (i.e., why would you need this information at runtime, what are you going to do with that information)?

Comment: You are right. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: "The app already uses tutorials in other parts therefore I want to integrate Compose UI support into the existing tutorial framework" -- I am a bit skeptical about this. Let's pretend that you did not have an existing tutorial framework. How would you solve the problem? My guess is that you would consider "in tutorial mode" to be part of your state, and your composables would render themselves accordingly.

Comment: I imagine a composable which takes the "composable to explain" as child. When in tutorial mode this composable has to occupy the whole screen, darken it and show the explanation text. To cut out the part which should not be occupied the position and size is needed.

Answer (score 0):

@CommonsWare's solution seems viable. Just create a boolean to denote whether tutorial is active, then use it inside the Composables to render accordingly. If you want the size and position of the items, you could simply store them inside the viewmodel. To get the values, just use the `onGloballyPositioned{...}` Modifier. You can retrieve the size by calling `it.size` (or name the labda parameter) inside it and  the coordinates with the same approach.

Also I would suggest that you implement the stuff from the ground up. Maybe migrate slowly in a scratch project. If you try to migrate with the same sematics as the view system, creating an unbalanced hybrid, you will not be able to get the full advantage of the declarative paradigm that Compose is built on.